# Creating a stop in snippet "string"

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I got this snippet and trying to create the next stop inside of the options. So first I select the type of, lets say I select `v-if="NEXT-SHOULD-BE-HERE"`. How can I do that?

```
"Select template": {
    "prefix": ["templatetype"],
    "body": [
        "<template ${1|#:,v-if=\"\",v-for=\"\"|}>",
        "  ${2}",
        "</template>"
    ],
    "description": "Create a template and select type"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to put a tabstop inside a choice item.  The [grammar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar) shows only `text` is available in a `choice`:

`choice      ::= '${' int '|' text (',' text)* '|}'`

Also this issue appears to be about what you are asking and it has been closed:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35779